# How to scrape the data from "https://www.nseindia.com/companies-listing/corporate-filings-event-calendar?days=7days"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to scrape the table from the "https://www.nseindia.com/companies-listing/corporate-filings-event-calendar?days=7days" website, where as the python output is scraping the table.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/companies-listing/corporate-filings-event-calendar?days=7days'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
print(soup)
data_array = soup.find(id='table-wrap my-3 borderSet maxHeight-900 scrollWrap').get_text().strip().split(":")
type(data_array)
```

the output is printing the HTML tag instead of the table.

Regards
karthi

Answer (score 0):

If you want table, there's a download link available. It's available as a csv file. You don't need any code. Why don't you just use that?

Answer (score 0):

this code will return you all table as list, put data_table as locator by xpath:

```
        data_table = self.find_element(table_locator).get_attribute('innerHTML').replace('<th></th>', '')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data_table, 'lxml')
    data_rows = soup.find_all('tr')
    rows_values_scrape = [[td.getText() for td in data_rows[i].findAll('td')]
                   for i, v in enumerate(data_rows)]
    rows_values = [x for x in rows_values_scrape if x]
    columns_scrape = [[td.getText() for td in data_rows[i].findAll('th')]
                   for i, v in enumerate(data_rows)]
    columns = [x for x in columns_scrape if x]
    table=[]
    if columns[1:] != []:
        for i, r in enumerate(columns[1:]):
            table.append([f'column: {columns[0][j]}, row_title: {columns[1:][i][0]}, cell: {rows_values[i][j]}' for j, c in enumerate(columns[0])])
    else:
        table=[f'column: {columns[0][j]}, cell: {rows_values[0][j]}' for j, c in enumerate(columns[0]) if columns[1:] == []]
    return table
```